# store data in database in background using multi-threading for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, ios4

I am working on a database based task, in that lots of data are coming from the server and that are needed to store in the database. the server will send all data in size of 300 to 400 and total data are 30000.

But this process is starting after some time interval and before that other server processes are running, My question is IS is possible to start the database process when application start with the Multi-threading , so that Data can be stored on different thread and the main functionality can be run on main thread.

Please help me how to deal with Multi threading in iPhone and how to deal with database using Multithreading for iPhone.

thanks in advance,